# Cannot access MySQL database remotely XAMPP

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to access a database remotely and I have not been successful yet. I have tried almost everything i can find on the internet but nothing seems to work.

First I used this command to grant permission to access the database

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;flush privileges;
```

According to what I understand this command will give access to everyone on the internet to the database but security is not an issue for me, so no worries there.

Just to confirm whether the permission has been granted or not I used

show grants;

and i got this

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I was expecting it to show me access for @% as well but it did not, I have done something wrong here that I m probably unaware of.

Just to check whether its actually working or not I tried to connect to the database using

```
# mysql -u root -p -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

and this is the output

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '14.97.0.20' (10061)
```

I have checked that the bind address has been commented
I have turned off my firewall (security is no issue)

Can you guys please tell me where am I going wrong with this

Comment: watch this tutorial https://youtu.be/1L9u3tbUVBU

Comment: Hi varunk, thankyou for the reference video but the problem still remains. I am able to grant permission and check that the permissions have been granted thanks to the video but when i try connecting to the database i encounter the same error. Just to clear it out the machines are not in the same network. 
I have seen articles where they are able to access the db given its on the same network. Any idea where am I going wrong?

Comment: did you set any password for your mysql ? change it etc

Comment: if it still doesnt work lease install xampp again once you have to write localhost/ the project name to access the project and for database you have to type http://localhost/phpmyadmin